# What happens when I hit quit in a cocoa program?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a Cocoa/Objective-C program, I set it up the way it wants, with a menu bar, etc, and the quit menu item comes pre-linked to FirstResponders Terminate method. Fine. But what happens in that method?

More importantly, how do I get things to happen on quit? I have an AppController object that is the delegate of the mainmenu, and is an object that I send messages to, etc. I put a terminate:(id) method in my AppController class, and those things seem to happen. The program ALSO seems to quit, although I'm not sure why.

So what is actually happening in the FirstResponder Terminate? if my AppController is the delegate, does that make it the first responder? otherwise, how does it get into the responder chain? (which it evidently is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> More importantly, how do I get things to happen on quit?

You can implement `NSApplicationDelegate`'s [`-applicationWillTerminate:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_27).